# Concat two String in JSF EL expression

Tags: java, string, jsf, el, concatenation

I have the following el expression:

```
<af:outputText value="#{viewArticle.publish ? ('Publish on ' + viewArticle.publishDate + ' by ' + viewArticle.publishFirstName + ' ' + viewArticle.publishLastName) : 'Draft version'}"/>
```

But I am getting

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Publish on "
```

How can I join the string?

Comment: You have to write your own EL string concat function, because EL understands + as an arithmetic operation.

Comment: @refrigerator that means in el this kind of function not available?

Comment: Actually you can, if the EL version is 2.0+  using concat method, which version of ADF Faces are you using?

Comment: @refrigerator I have ADF 11.1.1.6.0 which use jsf 1.2

Comment: http://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/17/using-custom-functions-in-el-expressions-in-jsf-1-x/ this will help you :)

Comment: You have to write a custom EL function. [This example](http://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/17/using-custom-functions-in-el-expressions-in-jsf-1-x/) will help you :)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the **String.concat** function:

`<af:outputText value="#{viewArticle.publish ? 'Publish on '.concat(viewArticle.publishDate).concat(' by ').concat(viewArticle.publishFirstName).concat(' ').concat(viewArticle.publishLastName) : 'Draft version'}"/>`

Answer (score 44):

You should write

```
value  = "#{someBean.aProperty}  something you want in between #{someBean.anotherProperty}"
```

Comment: That works for the attribute but does not help if you need the concatenated string as a function parameter in a JSF EL